# Execute .SQL in PowerShell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I wanted to know how I can run a .sql file which contains several queries in powershell

[image]

What I need is that through the command console of powershell, execute this .sql file and start creating the db with its respective tables from the querys that has this file, I understand that in linux I can do it, but I would like to know how to do it in powershell

from now on thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The powershell  command looks like this

```
C:\> cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p password ]schema_name} < DataBase72.sql"
```

there are [more Options for mysql.exe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the specifics, there are two general ways to do this:

1. Remember there's a reason it's named Power**Shell**: it's also a full command line shell. This means you can connect to MySql the same way as in other shells, using the same tools provided by the database (ie: mysql.exe, mysql-cli, etc)
2. Powershell can use .Net libraries, including the same .Net libraries used for connecting to MySql from a C# or VB.Net program. If [Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html) is available on the system, or if you can install it for the version of .Net available to you, you can create and use these ADO.Net objects from PowerShell code.